# how do i add the back icon to the left bar button?

Tags: ios, swift

I am new to ios development, i am trying to use the following code to push the current controller to next controller

```
    self.navigationController?.pushViewController(controller, animated: true)
```

However, when i proceed to the next controller, there is a back icon on the left bar button (Yes, that is exactly what i want). The problem is, since i intend to perform an unwind segue action, i have to manually add the bar button item to the new controller and control drag to the exit to perform the unwind segue action. OK thats fine, the thing is when i debug it, the back icon is missing! How do i make the back icon appear again?? I do not want just a simple text , i want an icon to lead the user to know that is a back button

if i didnt assign any bar button into the new controller, it will show like this

http://s17.postimg.org/duy58azxp/Screen_Shot_2016_02_16_at_2_13_27_PM.png

if i assign bar button item, and assign the title as back, the icon will show as this

http://s27.postimg.org/n8yngdqcx/Screen_Shot_2016_02_16_at_2_13_11_PM.png

Comment: are you hidden your back icon in any where in your code

Comment: i not even code anything on that button.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to do anything to the button. What you do need to do instead is the following:

1. Create a new class and override `UINavigationControllerDelegate`
2. Add the method `navigationController:animationControllerForOperation:fromViewController:toViewController:`
3. Inside the function mentioned above, add some logic like this:

```
func navigationController(navigationController: UINavigationController, animationControllerForOperation operation: UINavigationControllerOperation, fromViewController fromVC: UIViewController, toViewController toVC: UIViewController) -> UIViewControllerAnimatedTransitioning?
{
    if fromVC is YourOtherViewController && toVC is YourMainViewController {
        return CustomAnimator()
    }

    return nil
}
```

Where CustomAnimator is a subclass of `UIViewControllerAnimatedTransitioning`

4. Set the navigation controller's delegate in the storyboard.

To do step 4,

1. Drag an `Object` into the top bar of the view (it should go between `First Responder` and `Exit`, like so:
   [image: Object position]
2. In the Attributes Inspector, set the class of the new `Object` to whatever you named the file created in the first step.
3. Connect the `delegate` outlet from your `UINavigationController` to the `Object`

Answer (score 0):

Write this code in `viewDidLoad()`.

```
navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = UIBarButtonItem(image: UIImage(named: "imagename"), style: UIBarButtonItemStyle.Plain, target: self, action: "leftbuttonclick")
```